# Can't add ref to cloned element

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to clone a child component and add a ref to it like this:

```
let targetChild = null;
React.Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
    if (child.type.displayName === 'TargetChildElement') {
        targetChild = React.cloneElement(child, { ref: index });
    }
});
```

However, I'm getting an error when the child element is functional:

`Uncaught Error: Function components cannot have refs. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/1730

Comment: @JeremyHarris I don't get how I need to call `forwardRef` in my case since I'm not defining a new component, just cloning an existing one.